# Making an APNG or GIF animation with perl

Tags: perl, animated-gif, apng

What is please a good way to do an APNG or GIF animation with perl ?

I wish to create it from a group of PNG files, that I generate myself. Each of these files would be a frame of the final GIF animation.

Thanks.

Comment: GD or ImagickMagick come to mind as options.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the [GD Module](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD::Image::AnimatedGif). Also provide us some code if you can´t get through.